# Automatically rewriting URLs using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to **automatically** rewrite a URL to a virtual directory using `.htaccess`.

My rules are working but not automatically, so for example I have a file called `login.php` in the root directory and I want to rewrite to to a virtual directory to be like this `example.com/login/` instead of `example.com/login.php`, the below rule works fine for this purpose.

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^login/$ ./login.php [L,NC]
```

However, this won't rewrite the `login.php` file automatically. I need whenever a user requests the *login.php* file, the rule **automatically** redirects the user to `example.com/login/` and still serve the same content. How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to a redirect for that:

```
ewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /login\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /login/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule login/$ ./login.php [L,NC]
```